# can't install flashtext python library on windows anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, windows, anaconda

I am running Python on anaconda windows.
I need to use flashtext library and seems it's not possible if you run python on windows.
Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Using Windows 10 and Anaconda 2018.12 - Python 3.7, I ran the following in Anaconda prompt:

```
(base) C:\Users\john.doe>pip install flashtext
```

And it returned

```
Successfully installed flashtext-2.7
```

Testing revealed it works properly, however there are [some caveats](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) when mixing `pip` and `conda`.. please heed them.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda support FlashText library.

```
 conda install -c derickl flashtext
```

Comment: I had this result:
Solving environment: failed
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - flashtext

....

Comment: did you try 'pip install flashtext'

Comment: i need to install it on windows. Python is running under anaconda on windows